# Jquery UI use resizable and draggable at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Just wanted to resize and drag an image but `resizable` is not working.
Where is the issue ? I could not solve it.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qpeehsxn/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#wrapper').draggable();
  $('#image').resizable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" style="display:inline-block">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`draggable` and `resizable` are part of jquery-ui so you have to include it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#wrapper').draggable();
  $('#image').resizable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" style="display:inline-block">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: I included but not css.jquery-ui.css is required?

Comment: Without the UI-CSS the handle will not show, in fact the function is working: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpeehsxn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't currently referencing the jQuery UI Library (both CSS and Javascript), which is the actual library that handles the [`draggable()`](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [`resizable()`](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) functions :

```
<div id="wrapper" style="display:inline-block">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</div>
<!-- jQuery UI CSS Reference -->
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- jQuery Reference (required for jQuery UI) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI Reference -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Your Script Here -->
<script>
    $(function() {
         $('#wrapper').draggable();
         $('#image').resizable();
    });
</script>
```

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/mutetu/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]