# jQuery UI: two method in one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try add to resizable() in my loaded image from FileReader in javascript, but this method not working (img not display), because this element using draggable too.

HTML:

```
<div class="box--display--img"><img id="i" /></div>
<input id="f" type="file" />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#f").on("change", function(ev) {
    var f = ev.target.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function(ev2) {
      console.dir(ev2);
      $("#i").attr("src", ev2.target.result);
    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(f);
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#i").draggable({
    containment: "parent"
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#i").resizable();
});
```

Comment: set draggable to wrapper element of `#i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI use resizable and draggable at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939056/jquery-ui-use-resizable-and-draggable-at-the-same-time)